# Unity Firebase + AdMob conflict (GoogleAppMeasurement)

Tags: xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, admob, cocoapods

Unity: 2019.4.8f1

AdMob v5.4.0

Firebase v6.16.1 (Messaging & Analytics)

Target minimum iOS Version 12.0

### **Problem**

I can't build the project. XCode error:

```
../Libraries/Plugins/iOS/GADUAdLoader.h:5:9: 'GoogleMobileAds/GoogleMobileAds.h' file not found
```

When I trying to update pods terminal throw the next error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 6.32.2) was resolved to 6.32.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 6.32.2) was resolved to 6.32.2, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.8.2) was resolved to 6.8.2, which depends on
          GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.8.2)

    Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.68) was resolved to 7.68.0, which depends on
      GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 7.0)
```

### Attempts

1. Add 'pod 'GoogleAppMeasurement', '7.0'' to Podfile.

Result

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleAppMeasurement":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics (= 6.32.2) was resolved to 6.32.2, which depends on
      Firebase/Core (= 6.32.2) was resolved to 6.32.2, which depends on
        FirebaseAnalytics (= 6.8.2) was resolved to 6.8.2, which depends on
          GoogleAppMeasurement (= 6.8.2)

    Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (~> 7.68) was resolved to 7.68.0, which depends on
      GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 7.0)

    GoogleAppMeasurement (= 7.0)
```

2. Uninstall and install cocoapods

Result

Same error

**Project Podfile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '6.32.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.32.2'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '6.32.2'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.68'
end
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

`Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` version 7.68 is only compatible with Firebase 7.x. If you want to use Firebase 6.x, you need to use 7.67 or earlier.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Just delete at the top

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs'
```

my pod file

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
target 'UnityFramework' do
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.68'
end
```